# Azure Function App w/ 0Auth error - ERROR: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named

Tags: c#, azure, api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I need to add 0Auth to my Azure Function App, which will be triggered through HTTP request, POST, and I should retrieve the user details that I pass the credentials into the body. I'm quite newbie on coding, and all tutorials I have seen so far, due my unexeperience, it is a just bunch of non-sense code for me with many details that in my point of view just someone with experience would be able to follow. I was able to generate my token, but not pass it together in my request, also when I call the API it is throwing me the following error:

```
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: http://localhost:7235/api/.default, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. ERROR: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named http://localhost:7235/api/.default was not found in the tenant named <CN>. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

As a Token Provider, I'm using the class `AzureServiceTokenProvider();`, which I believe is causing this error. I looked for some alternatives for Token Providers, and I could find only the `TokenProver();` but I tried to use some of them and I was getting errors as well. I was requested to do everything using C# and nothing else, not the Portal Azure. The onlu thing I can use from Azure is the Azure Storage Account. I was able to create the "CRUD" system, and they are working fine. I don't have any more class related with token.

This is my code below:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Login(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "POST", Route = "login")] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("User", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] TableClient tdClient,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:7235/api/.default";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(url);

            var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateUserDto>(requestBody);
            var user = new User
            {
                email = input.email,
                password = input.password
            };

            string userToString = user.ToString();
            var stringContent = new StringContent(userToString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            return new OkObjectResult(response);
        }
```

I really don't want to use the `AzureServiceTokenProvider();` class. Is it possible to do that using the `TokenProvider();`. How can I do that? I hope I made myself clear. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to enforce authentication you should consider Azure Function/App Service Authentication or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#enable-app-service-authenticationauthorization

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I am looking for a solution that I can apply on code. That's why I came up to this issue.

Comment: You can apply code on it at least on the incoming claim. Thats the cool part actually. 
[FunctionName("MyIdentityFunction")]
        public static IActionResult Run
            ([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
             HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal claimIdentity)
        {
            log.LogInformation("User ID: " + claimIdentity.Identity.Name);